# How to effect change on Xamarin Forms Theme's, that actually works

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, themes

I have followed the process documented on the Microsoft Docs 
[micrsoft docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/material-theme)

added the theme in the Assembly Info and Android Manifest. 
but when the application is built and deployed to my Android device, still nothing. Is this common? or is there another work around?

Comment: i think have found a solution, from xamarin documentation rather microsoft docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/themes/light

Comment: You could refer to this document: https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/